# Should we change the font size within code tags (it is very small)

Tags: discussion, design

### EDIT: (jcolebrand)

### Do you want to see the code block font size changed? Vote up for yes, down for no.

And comment or upvote below with a size if yes. Thank you. - jco

---

### Original:

Is this intentional? It looks a little out of place.

I went over to SO to compare and there are font size is almost the same, but on this site there is a stark difference:

On [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/running-multiple-instances-on-the-same-host/6375#6375)

> [image]

On [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7625363/113124), as comparison

> [image]

Comment: Generally if you can suggest a better size, we can ask the team@ to look the situation, and maybe "correct" it, but I don't think too many people object to the smaller size. I for one am happy with the smaller size, as it gives more room for code on the screen.

Comment: @jcoldebrand: Can we keep the size comparable to the normal text size. Not noticeably smaller or bigger?

Comment: I almost always adjust my answers so code blocks don't add a horizontal scrollbar (at least in Chrome) - I hope no-one makes it bigger or I'm going to have to do a lot of editing :)

Comment: I concur @JackDouglas I dont' want it much larger.

Comment: @Lazer let's keep it simple. Let's let people vote this Q up or down, and after a couple months we should have an idea. I'll edit the Q.

Comment: Wow, only two people care about this question after all this time? I was going to up-vote because I don't like the smaller size when code is placed it *inline* (I don't mind it in blocks, it just `looks funny to me` when inline). But it doesn't seem like I should bother.

Comment: And I mean in a question/answer, not in a comment, where it looks fine. :-\ Here is an example from [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30584/1186): http://i.stack.imgur.com/J1D9g.png

Answer (score 5):

Indeed this is intentional; you'll also notice a smaller code font size on

http://codereview.stackexchange.com

and

http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay, thanks. But it does not look right, imo. For a minute I was confused if there was a new setting here to change the size of the code.

Comment: @Lazer: I like smaller code. Browsers can zoom or you can change font size in your browser

Comment: But @gbn, you can't zoom in on inline code but not the rest of the text. The problem I have is not that the text is small, but that inline code is noticeably smaller than the body text. Why can't they be the same size?